# Navbar-brand and hamburger icon arrangement

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```
<div class="clearfix">    
   <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-   
    toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2"> &#9776;
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm-up" href="/">Bootstrap</a>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="clearfix">    
   <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm-up" href="/">Bootstrap</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-   
    toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2"> &#9776;
   </button>
</div>
```

Both output Bootstrap before the hamburger icon. How can I put the hamburger before the bootstrap navbar-brand and possible pushing it to the right?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the icon on the right, then use the pull-right class in the button and have it before the link in the code.

```
<div class="clearfix">    
   <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up pull-right" type="button" data-   
    toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2"> &#9776;
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm-up" href="/">Bootstrap</a>
</div>
```

if you want the icon on the left - the have the pull-right in the link.

```
        <div class="clearfix">    
   <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up " type="button" data-   
    toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2"> &#9776;
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm-up pull-right" href="/">Bootstrap</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18740/)

```
<div class="clearfix pull-right">    
   <button class="pull-left navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-   
    toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar2"> &#9776;
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm-up" href="/">Bootstrap</a>
</div>
```

Comment: no Bootstrap on the left hamburger to the right or vice versa.